# How to use itext to span 2 columnns of a page?

Tags: itext

I am trying to do the following using itext and java through eclipse.I need to create a PDF which will consist of a no of multiple choice questions retrieved from database.The data retrieved is in the form of html tags hence for that i am using xml worker to parse it.I am able to retrieve the questions one by one from the database and add it to the pdf.But the problem is that it occupies only one side of a page while i need the questions to  cover 2 columns of a page.

When the end of the first PDF page is reached it should utilize the right hand corner of the first PDF page to add questions.Only when both left and right sides of a page are fully used it should move on to the next PDF page.

Now i managed to get the html data in 2 columns using ColumnText.But the problem i face now is that the questions retrieved from database do not appear in the format as intended.Each question is getting displayed on one line.

I entered the questions is this format:

1)What is 2+2=?

a)2

b)4

c)8

d)15

I want that the output on pdf should be as above.

However i get the following as output:

1)What is2+2=?a)2b)4c)8d)15

How do i preserve the html formatting ?????????

This is my code so far:

```
 import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.List;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.ElementHandler;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.ElementList;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.Pipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.Writable;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.WritableElement;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.end.PdfWriterPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext;

public class ColumnTextExample {
    public static final float[][] COLUMNS = {
         { 36, 36, 224, 579 } , { 230, 36, 418, 579 }

        };
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, DocumentException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\columns.pdf"));

        document.open();


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test3", "root", "root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from exam2");
        int size=0;
        while (rs.next()){
        size++;
        };

        ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery("select * from exam2");
        String[] myStringArray = new String[size];
        int i=0;
        while (rs1.next()){
           myStringArray[i]=rs1.getString("paper");
           i++;
     }

        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        for (String article : myStringArray) {

           ct.addElement(createPhrase(article,writer,document));

            ct.addElement(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
     }
        ct.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        ct.setExtraParagraphSpace(55);
        ct.setLeading(0, 1.2f);
        ct.setFollowingIndent(27);
        int linesWritten = 0;
        int column = 0;
        int status = ColumnText.START_COLUMN;
        while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(status)) {
            ct.setSimpleColumn(
                    COLUMNS[column][0], COLUMNS[column][1],
                    COLUMNS[column][2], COLUMNS[column][3]);
            ct.setYLine(COLUMNS[column][3]);
            status = ct.go();
            linesWritten += ct.getLinesWritten();
            column = Math.abs(column - 1);
            if (column == 0)
                document.newPage();
        }

        ct.addElement(new Phrase("Lines written: " + linesWritten));
        ct.go();
        document.close();
    }
 public static  Phrase createPhrase(String myString, PdfWriter writer, Document document) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Phrase p = new Phrase();
        String myString2=myString+"<html><body><br></br></body></html>";
        String k="<br></br>";
        XMLWorkerHelper xwh = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(myString.getBytes());
        ElementList myList = new ElementList();
        ElementList myList1 = new ElementList();
      xwh.parseXHtml(myList,new StringReader(myString2));

      p.addAll(myList);

  return p;
}
    }
```

When i use `XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(name1));` i am able to preserve the html formatting such as new line.

The below code helps me retrieve html data from DB and parse it while preserving the formatting.However it prints to the pdf in a single column

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import  com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.sql.*;


public class GeneratePDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
             OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Test.pdf"));
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
            document.open();

                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test3", "root", "root");
                   Statement st=con.createStatement();

                   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select paper from exam2 ");
                   String name1="";
                   while (rs.next()){
                       String name = rs.getString("paper");
                       //out.println(name);
                       name1=name;


            /*String k="<h1 style='text-align: center;'><strong>Maths&nbsp;Question2 Paper</strong></h1>"+
"<pre><strong>1)What is the sum of 2+2??<br /></strong><strong>a)3<br /></strong><strong>b)5<br /></strong><strong>c)4<br /></strong><strong>d)1</strong></pre>"+
"<pre><strong>2)What is the sum of 5+2??<br /></strong><strong>a)3<br />b)5<br />c)7<br />d)1</strong></pre>"+
"<pre>&nbsp;</pre>";*/
                   System.out.println(name1);

            //InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(name1.getBytes());
            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(name1));
                   }


            document.close();
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing the HTML to a `Document`. This means you want iText to organize all content on one page, using one column defined by the page size (in your case A4) and the page margins (in your case 36pt on each side).

If you want to organize the content differently, you should use the `parseXHTML()` method that takes an `ElementHandler` as parameter and pass an [`ElementList`](http://api.itextpdf.com/xml/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/ElementList.html) object. This list will then contain a `List` of `Element` objects that you can feed to a `ColumnText` object. With the `ColumnText` class, you can define multiple rectangles on a page, and use the `go()` method to fill these rectangles with the content from the `ElementList`.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail.???I'm having a tough time trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Replace `parseXHtml(writer, document, is)` with `parseXHtml(myList, is)` where `myList` is created as this: `ElementList myList = new ElementList();` Read the iText documentation to find out how to use `ColumnText`. If you don't understand: show us what you've got so far.

Comment: You have posted an additional question as an answer. I've flagged it as "not an answer" and I didn't reply to it, because that answer will most likely be removed. Looking at your additional question, I have the impression that you don't know the difference between *text mode* and *composite mode*. It's as if you copy/pasted a random `ColumnText` example from Chapter 3 of my book without reading Chapter 3. I get the feeling that you want me to copy/paste my book on StackOverflow. Surely you understand that my publisher would sue me if I did such a thing ;-)

Comment: Yes you are right.Ijust copy pasted the code.!!Am i suppose to use PDF cell to achieve what i want?

Comment: You're confusing me. Why are you suddenly talking about a cell in a table? You need to use `ColumnText` in *composite mode* instead of *text mode*. **As documented,** that's done by using `addElement()` instead of `addText()`.

Comment: Well, if you don't show any code, you shouldn't expect any answer (because as far as we know, it should work).

Comment: HI,i have updated my question and pasted my code..please do have a look...i have also used the addElement feature.I am able to parse the html but however i do not get the html output in the desired format

Comment: *"I do not get the html output in the desired format"* is very vague. Knowing that HTML is a bad format to define a layout, you shouldn't be surprised that the PDF looks very different from what you see in a browser. PDF is a page description language and browsers don't need to obey the concept of pages. Maybe you're expecting too much...

Comment: Thats strange..when i write a simple program to write the contents of HTML to PDF the formatting is preserved and my output is in the desired format.Its only when i try to modify my code and use 2 columns of a PDF is when i face the issue

Comment: Without a SSCCE, nobody will be able to answer your question. (See http://sscce.org/ )

Comment: I posted the code which helps me preserve HTML formatting.However the only issue with that code is that i am unable to print to pdf using 2 columns.

Comment: ON one hand i have a code which helps me parse html and also print it in 2 columns but formatting such as new line is not preserved.Whereas on the other hand i have code which helps me preserve the html formatting  such as new line and parse it but i am not able to print to 2 columns using that code.